# Magento redirects to base url using 302, how do I get it to use 301

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, seo, magento-1.4

I've notice in firebug that the non-www version of my magento store redirects to the www version using `302`. For SEO purposes I want it to redirect using `301`.

**How I tried to fix it**

I went to the System > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options and my setting Redirect to Base URL if requested URL doesn't match it is set to Yes (there are only 2 options: Yes or No)[image: Magento 1.4 URL Rewrite options]

**Imporantant notes**

I'm using Magento v1.4.0.1
My `.htaccess` file contains the following, in regards to URL Rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I change the redirect method to `301`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the last line to this:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301,L]
```

See [Apache mod_rewrite RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) the section about flags.

Comment: I got a `500 Internal Server Error` when I tried this approach.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the `space` after the comma. Not sure, if that is a syntax error in the rewrite URL. Please try again.

Comment: Oh it's Friday...it should be: "...syntax error in the RewriteRule."

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore as of 1.6. Instead this can be set directly in the Admin Panel, see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

As of 1.6.2.0 there seems to be an option to select the redirect method in the Admin Panel,  no need to modify the *.htaccess*.

Simply go to *System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options* and set *Auto-redirect to Base URL* to your preferred method.

Comment: the question was for magento 1.4.0.1 and there's no option in the admin pannel for that.

Comment: Absolutely, but it's also one of the first results that comes up on Google when searching for a solution to this problem, so I thought I'd amend the current solution for anybody who finds this via Google. :)

Comment: I've found this doesn't work. Using http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/, www. example.com is showing as 302, but example.com (minus www.) is showing 301.